# Get all the legends on the top of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

[image]I have a multiple plot within a plot, generated by `ggpubr::ggarrange()`. However the legends only appears for the first plot i.e., A and B. I wanted to get the legends for rest of the colours, C, D, E on the top. Setting `common.legend = TRUE` only gives the first two legends.

Thanks for the help!

```r
library(ggpubr)

arranged_plot <- ggarrange(
  plot_list[[1]] + rremove("ylab") + rremove("xlab") + rremove("x.text"),
  plot_list[[2]] + rremove("ylab") + rremove("xlab") + rremove("axis.text"),
  plot_list[[3]] + rremove("ylab") + rremove("xlab"),
  plot_list[[4]] + rremove("ylab") + rremove("xlab") + rremove("y.text"),
  labels = NULL, ncol = 2, nrow = 2,align = "hv", 
  font.label = list(size = 10, color = "black", face = "bold", family = NULL, position = "top"),
  common.legend=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with `ggarrange`, but if you're willing to look at other methods, here are two options:

1. Using `patchwork` (and [collecting legends](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html#controlling-guides)).

   ```r
   # sample data where each elem has cyl=4 and another cyl
   mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
   mtdat1 <- lapply(c(6, 8), function(CY) {
     subset(mtcars, cyl %in% c(4, CY)) |>
       transform(CY = CY)
   })
   plot_list <- lapply(mtdat1, function(dat) {
     ggplot(dat, aes(mpg, disp, color = cyl)) +
       geom_point() +
       scale_color_manual(values = setNames(c("gray", "red", "blue"), c(4, 6, 8)), drop = FALSE)
   })

   library(patchwork)
   plot_list[[1]] + plot_list[[2]] +
     plot_layout(nrow = 1, guides = "collect") &
     theme(legend.position = "top")
   ```

   [image: ggplot2 with patchwork]
2. Facets.

   ```r
   # sample data, starting with `mtdat1` from above
   mtdat2 <- do.call(rbind, args = mtdat1)
   ggplot(mtdat2, aes(mpg, disp, color = cyl)) +
     facet_wrap(~ CY) +
     geom_point() +
     scale_color_manual(values = setNames(c("gray", "red", "blue"), c(4, 6, 8)), drop = FALSE) +
     theme(legend.position = "top")
   ```

   [image: ggplot2 with facets]

   If you prefer to not have the facet strips, we can remove those in a theme:

   ```r
   ggplot(mtdat2, aes(mpg, disp, color = cyl)) +
     facet_wrap(~ CY) +
     geom_point() +
     scale_color_manual(values = setNames(c("gray", "red", "blue"), c(4, 6, 8)), drop = FALSE) +
     theme(legend.position = "top", strip.text.x = element_blank())
   ```

   [image: ggplot2 with facets, no strips]

   I think there are two advantages to facets:

   1. Simpler code, more efficient, allowing ggplot to handle everything in one step.
   2. Since we don't explicitly free the scales (e.g., not doing `scales="free"`), the axes are all on the same scale, no need to explicitly control them. For comparisons as in your graph, this can be a big difference in visualizing the differences between levels. (Compare this plot with the first plot using `patchwork`, though those axis limits can easily be fixed as well.)